# HSTS compatible .htaccess redirect from non-www to www that preserves URL path

Tags: htaccess, redirects, https, security-certificate

**UPDATE:** The redirect actually does work! The site is a friends site and I was coming up with solutions and sending them to him. Turns out his website is running Joomla. After further troubleshooting it came to light that he messed up and **did not** add the redirect to the **specific redirect section in Joomla's .htaccess file**. Once it was added to the proper location in Joomla's .htaccess file everything worked as expected.

**UPDATE 2:** I also wanted to mention that in order for the redirect to work properly, besides having a **Wildcard** SSL certificate, the domain also needs a **Wildcard subdomain**. This was already in place but I wanted to mention this for others to have this information.

##############################

I have reviewed several other questions that come close to what I need but so far nothing I've found seems to work.

I'm trying to figure out how to create a redirect in the htaccess file from **non-www** to **www** AND **preserve the URL path** and do it all in a way that is compatible with HSTS.
Example, if I enter "http://example.org/page01" I would expect it to redirect to "httpS://www.example.org/page01".

Information about the setup:

The site has a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate (wildcard certificate).
In the control panel the Preferred domain is "none". Options are "none", "example.org", & "www.example.org". It is set to "none" because if this option is set "www.example.org" then https://hstspreload.org will throw the following error:

> "Error: HTTP redirects to www first`http://example.org` (HTTP) should immediately redirect to `https://example.org` (HTTPS) before adding the www subdomain. Right now, the first redirect is to `https://www.example.org/`. The extra redirect is required to ensure that any browser which supports HSTS will record the HSTS entry for the top level domain, not just the subdomain."

Setting it to **"none"** in the control panel settings AND also setting the domain to **"Permanent SEO-safe 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS"** solves that problem.

At this point in the setup, "http://example.org/page01" redirects normally to "httpS://example.org/page01"

Then, to make the change from **non-www** to **www**, I've placed the following in the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^((www|valid1|valid2|valid3)\.example\.org)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is this redirect added to the .htaccess file **does not** preserve the URL path.
So when I enter "http://example.org/page01" I end up with "https://www.example.org/".

Since the URL path IS preserved when going from http to https before the redirect is added to the .htaccess file, I have to assume there is a mistake in it that is causing the URL path to not be preserved.

Any ideas what I need to change in the redirect to accomplish my goal?
I would also be open to a completely different redirect that does all the above BUT does not rely on turning on the "Permanent SEO-safe 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS" in the control panel.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: HSTS has nothing to do with redirections. HSTS is just a signal (either from previous visits or from the preloading list) that the browser should immediately and only do `https://` calls and not `http://` one. This happens on the client (the client decides the scheme to use) before any kind of server redirections can happen.

Comment: Your `RewriteRule` seems fine and difficult to spot a problem, it can depend on many other parts of your configuration. You either need to give the real names involved if you want people to test, or you have to look in your logfiles, you can increase verbosity level of `mod_rewrite` to see what happens. Or show real HTTP(S) exchanges, like with `curl` or `wget`.  Also note that for simple cases (which you fit it), using `Redirect` directive may be far simpler that using `mod_rewrite`, a module that is very powerful and hence more complicated to setup.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you for the reply but I think you misunderstand the question. In order for the site to be compatible with HSTS, when using **www**, it must go from **http** to **https** immediately then to **www**. It **can't** go from `http://www` to `httpS://www`. Hence the error message from the hstspreload.org website. This is why I specified that the solution needs to be compatible with HSTS.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek If I was to take the control panel settings out of the equation, ie going from **http** to **https** what should be added/modified in the current redirect to make this work?

Comment: Your rule should preserve the path.   Some other rule must be doing the redirect.  What else do you have in your .htacess and apache config files?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks! I've updated the question to clarify that it does work. The redirect was entered in the wrong location in the Joomla .htaccess file as it has a specific location for redirects.

Comment: Glad it is fixed.  I'll leave the question closed because you don't need any answers.

Comment: Does this (redirect) now pass the "HSTS preload" test? (It's just that a requirement of HSTS preload is that the redirect (non-www to www on HTTPS only) must include the HSTS header - this is not evident in what you've posted?)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Since the OP has updated the "question" _twice_ with an answer to benefit "future readers" - it may be preferable to _reopen_ the question so an actual answer can be posted (and accepted)?

Comment: @MrWhite  Questions caused by typos or code in the wrong place are very specific to the site in question and not likely to help future visitors.